# Threadpool executor not executing multiple threads

Tags: python

I'm creating threadpool with 3 workers and assign the executor 10 tasks.

When I execute the tasks I don't get any outputs.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import threading
import random

def task(n):
 import sleep
 sleep.time(5)
 print("Processing {}".format(n))

def main():
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)    
    for each in range(10):
        executor.submit(task, each)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an ImportError exception when you try to import `sleep` in the function.

Change the function to

```
import time
def task(n):
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Processing {}".format(n))
```

---

If you want to see those errors (from your original `task`), change `main` to accumulate the futures and return them. Then iterate over the futures and print the result.

```
...

def main():
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
    futures = []
    for each in range(10):
        futures.append(executor.submit(task, each))
    return futures

if __name__ == '__main__':
    futures = main()
    for future in futures:
        print(future, future.exception())
```

Which produces something like this

```
>>>
<Future at 0x34712d0 state=finished raised ImportError> No module named 'sleep'
<Future at 0x34b0e70 state=finished raised ImportError> No module named 'sleep'
<Future at 0x34b0ff0 state=finished raised ImportError> No module named 'sleep'
<Future at 0x34be170 state=finished raised ImportError> No module named 'sleep'
<Future at 0x34be1f0 state=finished raised ImportError> No module named 'sleep'
<Future at 0x34be270 state=finished raised ImportError> No module named 'sleep'
<Future at 0x34be2f0 state=finished raised ImportError> No module named 'sleep'
<Future at 0x34be370 state=finished raised ImportError> No module named 'sleep'
<Future at 0x34be3f0 state=finished raised ImportError> No module named 'sleep'
<Future at 0x34be470 state=finished raised ImportError> No module named 'sleep'
>>>
```

Comment: thanks..why doesn't threadpoolexecutor doesn't throw a exception for my wrong import. That makes debugging difficult.

Comment: Without thinking too hard about it I'd say because that is how it was designed. looks like *they* expected the tasks to return a value that you would retrieve via the future object so the problem would be caught during the retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement wwii's answer, before using `ThreadPoolExecutor`, I suggest to test with a normal thread at first.

As `ThreadPoolExecutor` is designed to throw exception when you want to get the result(`future.result()`), But sometimes we don't even care about the results. In this case, the task will implicitly fail without any notification.